# PHP array_rand in loop where value is always different from previous value

Tags: php

I have a PHP script as follows:

```
<?php
$a = [1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3];

for ($x=1; $x<10; $x++) {
    $r = array_rand($a);
    echo $a[$r] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

The output for this is random every time, but as an example it may be this:

2
1
3
3
2
3
1
3
2

What I'm trying to achieve is to make sure that each time a value is output it is different from the previous value. So in the example above I don't want 3 3 to occur.

I tried to come up with my own solution which involved storing the "current" output value in a variable called `$current_value` and making sure it's not what's going to be output next:

```
<?php
$a = [1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3];

$current_value = false;
for ($x=1; $x<10; $x++) {

    if ($current_value) {
        $r = array_rand($a);
        while ($current_value !== $r) {
            echo $a[$r] . '<br>';
            $current_value = $a[$r];
        }
    } else {
        $r = array_rand($a);
        echo $a[$r] . '<br>';
        $current_value = $a[$r];
    }
}
?>
```

Although I don't get the same value appearing in sequence (at least from what I've tested) the loop only outputs a random number of figures which is usually less than `$x<10`. My guess here is that there's nothing to handle `$current_value == $r` so it simply outputs nothing?

Please could someone advise on how to achieve this? The expected output is 9 (or whatever the `for` loop counter is set to) integers with no overlap in the sequence, e.g.

2
1
3
1
2
3
1
3
2

**Edit: The value which is output must always be 1, 2 or 3. This is why I was using `$a` as defined.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this code would do what you want:

```
<?php
$a = [1, 2, 3];

$current_value = false;
for ($x=1; $x<10; $x++) {
    $r = array_rand($a, 1);
    if ($current_value !== $r) {
        echo $a[$r] . '<br>';
        $current_value = $r;
    }else{
        $x--;
    }
}
```

Comment: The number which is output must be 1, 2 or 3. That's why I was using an indexed array. The code above does seem to work but is giving me value 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: instead of printing the index I've had it print the value now. Should run better

Answer (score 2):

Just make a recursive function.

A function to sort another number if is equal to the last one:

```
function myRand(array $array , $lastValue = null)
{
    $sorted = $array[array_rand($array)];   
    return $sorted == $lastValue ? myRand($array , $sorted) : $sorted;
}
```

And the function to do the length/ocurrences of new random array:

```
function myArrayRand(array $array , $length)
{
    $sortedArray = [];
    while(count($sortedArray) < $length)
    {
        $sortedArray[] = myRand($array , end($sortedArray));
    }

    return $sortedArray;    
}
```

Execute:

```
var_dump(myArrayRand([1 , 2 , 3] , 10));
```

Result:

```
array(10) {
   [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(3)
      [2]=>
      int(2)
      [3]=>
      int(3)
      [4]=>
      int(1)
      [5]=>
      int(3)
      [6]=>
      int(1)
      [7]=>
      int(2)
      [8]=>
      int(1)
      [9]=>
      int(2)
}
```

As `array_rand` return the randomized key from the array, I've put the sorted return as key from `$array`. That's why you don't need use an indexed array.

Comment: That's giving me Parse error: parse error, expecting `{` on the line which begins `function myArrayRand(array $array , int $length) : array`. I've copied/pasted it exactly into my script.

Comment: @Andy That's because I wrote in PHP 7 and you're using an old version of PHP. I'll downgrade to PHP < 7.

Answer (score 0):

Like this.use `goto`.The `goto` operator can be used to jump to another section in the program.

```
<?php
$a = [1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3];

$current_value = false;
for ($x=1; $x<10; $x++) {

    if ($current_value) {
        loop: $r = array_rand($a);
        if($current_value !== $r){
             echo $a[$r] . '<br>';
             $current_value = $a[$r];
        }
        else{
           goto loop; 
        }

    } else {
        $r = array_rand($a);
        echo $a[$r] . '<br>';
        $current_value = $a[$r];
    }
}
?>
```

For more see docs http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$a = [1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3];
$pre_index=-1;
for ($x=1; $x<10; $x++) {

   $r = array_rand($a);
   if($pre_index==-1){

        echo $a[$r] . '<br>';
         $pre_index=$r;
   }else {

       while($pre_index==$r){

          $r = array_rand($a);

              }


    echo $a[$r] . '<br>';
    $pre_index=$r;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have fully understand, but maybe you after something like this:

```
$a = [1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3];
$prev_value = false;
$results = [];
for ($x=1; $x<10; $x++) {
    $rand = array_rand($a);
    if($prev_value == $rand){
      do{
        $rand = array_rand($a);
      }while($prev_value === $rand);
}
$results[] = $rand;
$prev_value = $rand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with end() function . Below code may help you

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
$out = array();
for ($x=1; $x<=10; $x++) {

$r = array_rand($a);
if(!end($out)== $r)
{
     $out[] = $r;
     echo $a[$r] . '<br>';
}
else
{
    $x=$x-1;
}

}
```